# javascript binding object's prototype function

Tags: javascript, object, underscore.js, prototype-programming

How would I bind the this pointer in the objects prototype to the object's instance?

```
function Foo(){ }
Foo.prototype.f1 = function(){this.f2();} //is wrong because 'this' does not refer to Foo instance
Foo.prototype.f2 = function(){}
```

This is really annoying. Can anyone help? I tried doing _.bindAll(this,'f1','f2') inside Foo's constructor but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention in a comment that you are setting `f1` as event handler with:

```
canvas.addListner('mousedown',this.f1, false)
```

Instead, you can pass a closure:

```
var self = this;
canvas.addListner('mousedown',function() {
    self.f1();
}, false);
```

or use the `bind` methods of the Underscore.js library:

```
canvas.addListner('mousedown', _.bind(this.f1, this), false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code would work correctly if you used `var foo = new Foo();`. Then, just use `foo.f1();`. foo will be `this` in `f1`.

The reason is that when you use `new` against a constructor function, a `_proto` link will be attached to the object that will be the new instance. This `_proto_` link points to the prototype of the constructor function. At runtime, if an accessed property/method of the instance does not exist on the instance directly, the interpreter will follow the `_proto_`, and try to access the property/method there.

If you want to call a function with an explicit object as `this`, you can do `myFunc.call(myObjThatWillBeThis)`.

Comment: The problem is, sorry I wasn't clear, imagine f1 being a onMouseDown function calling f2, where the onMouseDown is a registered as a listener for canvas via canvas.addListner('mousedown',this.f1,false) in Foo's constructor

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be changed to:

```
function Foo() {
  this.f1 = function() {
    this.f2();
  }
  this.f2 = function() {
  }
}
```

Comment: That is what I ended up doing, but that is just ugly. I would prefer to 'separate' out the interface

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    var Foo = function() {};
    Foo.prototype.f1 = function() {this.f2();};
    Foo.prototype.f2 = function() {};
    var foo = new Foo();
    var proxyFn = function(fooInstance) {
        fooInstance.f1();
    };
    canvas.addListener('mousedown', proxyFn(foo), false);
```

Or something more generic:

```
    var bindFunction = function(fnToBind, scopeObj) {
        return function() {  // closure scope will contain bindFunction args
            fnToBind.call(scopeObj);
        };
    };
    var Foo = function() {};
    Foo.prototype.f1 = function() {this.f2();};
    Foo.prototype.f2 = function() {};
    var foo = new Foo();
    var proxyFn = bindFunction(Foo.prototype.f1, foo);
    canvas.addListener('mousedown', proxyFn, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
function Foo() {
    this.f1 = this.f1.bind(this);
    this.f2 = this.f2.bind(this);
}

Foo.prototype.f1 = function () { this.f2(); };
Foo.prototype.f2 = function () { console.log("f2"); };

var foo = new Foo();
var f = foo.f1;
f();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VYdNx/3/

As does this:

```
function Foo() {
    _.bindAll(this);
}

Foo.prototype.f1 = function () { this.f2(); };
Foo.prototype.f2 = function () { console.log("f2"); };

var foo = new Foo();
var f = foo.f1;
f();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VYdNx/2/